# Adding a BCC to a multipart ActionMailer action makes it not send as multipart, but garbage

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, multipart

I have code that looks like this:

```
def coupon_available_notice(order, bcc=false)
  # [...]
  headers = {
    :to       => @user.email,
    :from     => "info@domain.com",
    :subject  => subject
  }
  headers[:bcc] = "remail@domain.com" if bcc == true
  mail(headers)
end
```

and when bcc is true - the message gets sent as plain text, and all the multipart boundaries and code show up in the e-mail as plain text garbage.  When bcc is false, it sends just fine.

Why would that happen??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this is what I needed:

```
def coupon_available_notice(order, bcc=false)
  # [...]
  h = {
    :to       => @user.email,
    :from     => "info@domain.com",
    :subject  => subject
  }
  h[:bcc] = "remail@domain.com" if bcc == true
  mail(h)
end
```

headers is a reserved keyword within ActionMailer actions, so it was apparently setting bcc in some non-standard way or something.  Just by changing it to 'h', the problem disappeared!

Stupid mistake?  Maybe. But I bet someone else makes the same one ;)